# How can I install a NuGet package on OSX?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am starting a new MVC 6 application on my macbook and want to serve static files, therefore I must use `UseStaticFiles()` which requires me to install a NuGet package on my project. I can't find any documentation regarding how to accomplish this in OSX. Has someone figured it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've installed the required bits from [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-mac.html).

After whitch the DNX utility (DNU) is your friend.  You can install a package indirectly by putting the package, in your case "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles", in your project.json and calling `dnu restore`.

Or directly by calling `dnu install Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles`.

[This tutorial](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html) also shows a workflow that references `dnu` to restore depdenencies.

Comment: I don't see any references to `dnu` in that link. Is `dnu` still the recommended way of installing NuGet packages?